# Why is fc-cache not installing fonts for me in Fedora 15

Tags: linux, fonts, fedora, fontconfig

I have all the fonts I want in the directory ~/winFonts. In this directory there are a number of symlinks to the real font files. Now I run

```
fc-cache -fv .winfonts
```

And I see a message saying 453 new fonts, but I can't seem to use these fonts in any application. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out with a little help from some people on the fedora-qa irc channel.
The important thing to realize is that the command above doesn't actually add the .winfonts directory to the list of directories which fontconfig searches for fonts.

In order to add this directory, you can edit the .font.conf file in your home directory, and add

```
<dir>/home/varun/.winFonts</dir>
```

to the xml as a child of fontconfig.

Then running the `fc-cache -fv` command will result in the fonts being added to the list of available fonts.